# Querying a sub-group of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to formulate a query to get an answer from my data. The data is sales data where the customer may make several orders on a day and each invoice may consist of multiple lines. The data looks roughly like this:

```
Customer | Invoice Date | Invoice Number | Stock | Total Value
---------------------------------------------------------------
Acme     | 01/01/2023   | 1234           | Cod   | £20
Acme     | 01/01/2023   | 1234           | Hake  | £15
Acme     | 01/01/2023   | 2468           | Cod   | £10
Acme     | 01/01/2023   | 2468           | Hake  | £12
Acme     | 02/01/2023   | 3699           | Cod   | £20
Acme     | 02/01/2023   | 4567           | Hake  | £15
Acme     | 03/01/2023   | 9876           | Cod   | £10
Acme     | 03/01/2023   | 9876           | Hake  | £1
Beta     | 01/01/2023   | 8976           | Cod   | £10
Beta     | 01/01/2023   | 8976           | Hake  | £15
Beta     | 01/01/2023   | 5432           | Cod   | £5
Beta     | 01/01/2023   | 5432           | Hake  | £12
Beta     | 02/01/2023   | 2233           | Cod   | £20
Beta     | 02/01/2023   | 2233           | Hake  | £15
Beta     | 02/01/2023   | 1590           | Cod   | £10
Beta     | 02/01/2023   | 1590           | Hake  | £15
```

What I'm trying to find is the total sales, the average spend per day and per invoice and a count of the invoices which fall below a given threshold (say £25), something like this

```
Customer | Sales Total | Days Ordered Count | Invoice Count | Average per Invoice |  Invoice < £25
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Acme     |     £103    |           3        |      5        |          £20.60     |      4
Beta     |     £102    |           2        |      4        |          £25.50     |      1
```

I can get the first five columns ok, but I'm stumped about how to approach the last column. This is the SQL I use for the first five columns, which works.

```
select Customer,sum(Sales_Total) AS Sales Total,
    count(distinct Invoice_Date) AS Days ordered Count,
    COUNT(distinct Invoice_Number) AS Invoice Count,
    sum(Sales_Total)/count(distinct Invoice_Number) AS Average per Invoice,
from sales_2023
group by Customer
order by Customer;
```

I've tried window functions, but I got rather unexpected results, certainly not what I was looking for. I've also tried a subquery, but I don't know how to aggregate the different lines on an invoice together in the subquery, so that doesn't work either.

Any pointers on how to approach this would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql code with two sub queries for better readability. You can merge them into one if needed.

```
select subset_one.customer,subset_one.Sales_Total,
       subset_one.Days_ordered_Count,
       subset_one.Invoice_Count,
       subset_one.Average_per_Invoice,
       subset_two.count_less_25
    from
    (
        select  customer,sum(total_value) AS Sales_Total,
                count(distinct Invoice_Date) AS Days_ordered_Count,
                COUNT(distinct Invoice_Number) AS Invoice_Count,
                sum(total_value)/count(distinct Invoice_Number) AS Average_per_Invoice
        from sales_2023 group by Customer
    ) subset_one
        inner join
    (
    select subset_lt.customer, sum(subset_lt.less_than_25) as count_less_25
    from
        (
            select customer,Invoice_Number, (case when sum(total_value) < 25 then 1 else 0 end) as less_than_25
            from    sales_2023 group by Customer,Invoice_Number 
        ) subset_lt group by subset_lt.Customer
    ) subset_two
    on
    subset_one.customer = subset_two.customer
```

Adding DB fiddle link
[Less than 25](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ac45wMzMZLM8xgU1PTxuUm/1)

Comment: This worked, thankyou. I'm not sure I fully understand why yet, but now I have a working example I'll get there eventually!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to calculate the sales total and invoice total for each invoice by grouping it under `Customer` and `Invoice_Number`. Then, in the outer query, it sums up the count of invoices where the `Invoice_Total` is less than `£25` for each customer.

```
SELECT 
    Customer,
    SUM(Sales_Total) AS Sales_Total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Date) AS Days_Ordered_Count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number) AS Invoice_Count,
    SUM(Sales_Total) / COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number) AS Average_per_Invoice,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Invoice_Total < 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Invoice_Less_Than_25
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Customer,
        Invoice_Number,
        Invoice_Date,
        SUM(Total_Value) AS Sales_Total,
        SUM(Total_Value) AS Invoice_Total
    FROM sales_2023
    GROUP BY Customer, Invoice_Number, Invoice_Date
) AS subquery
GROUP BY Customer
ORDER BY Customer;
```

Comment: I got this working in the end too, so many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using a subquery to first calculate the total value per invoice and then using a conditional aggregation in your main query to count the `invoices` with a value below the given threshold. Something like:

```sql
SELECT 
    Customer,
    SUM(Invoice_Total) AS Sales_Total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Date) AS Days_Ordered_Count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number) AS Invoice_Count,
    ROUND(SUM(Invoice_Total) / COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number), 2) AS Average_per_Invoice,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Invoice_Total < 25 THEN Invoice_Number ELSE NULL END) AS Invoice_Less_Than_25
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Customer, 
        Invoice_Date, 
        Invoice_Number, 
        SUM(Total_Value) AS Invoice_Total
    FROM sales_2023
    GROUP BY Customer, Invoice_Date, Invoice_Number
) AS invoice_totals
GROUP BY Customer
ORDER BY Customer;
```

***[DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8D55g3tB2iq1krD6D1RxW3/3)***